How to detect a change in the value of “editMode” from a toolbar?
Let's use a selectable List as follows:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var elements: Set<UUID> = [.init(), .init(), .init()]
    @State private var selection: Set<UUID> = []
    
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(
                elements.sorted(),
                id: \.self,
                selection: $selection,
                rowContent: { Text(String(describing: $0)) }
            )
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing, content: {
                    EditButton()
                })
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading, content: {
                    Button(selection.count == elements.count ? "Unselect All" : "Select All", action: {
                        selection = selection.count == elements.count ? [] : elements
                    })
                    .opacity(editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? false ? 1 : 0) // FIXME: `editMode` value change is not detected
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

Although changing the value of editMode correctly updates the UI, it is not detected in the toolbar modifier.
Why ?
Tested in Xcode 16 beta 3.

I'm not sure if this is intentional or not. One possible explanation is that SwiftUI fails to (or is not designed to) find an environment value in ContentView as a dependency of a tool bar button.
This works as expected if you extract the tool bar button into its own View:
struct SelectAllButton: View {
    let elements: Set<UUID>
    @Binding var selection: Set<UUID>
    
    // importantly, read the environment from this extracted view
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(selection.count == elements.count ? "Unselect All" : "Select All", action: {
            selection = selection.count == elements.count ? [] : elements
        })
        .opacity(editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing ?? false ? 1 : 0)
    }
}

ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
    SelectAllButton(elements: elements, selection: $selection)
}

